# Why Artifactory Maven and Oracle fail to communicate?

Tags: oracle, maven, artifactory

I hope an answer will be a universal guide on how to connect Maven, Oracle And Artifactory and will become most usefull webpage on the net. Most likely this question will be marked down, but I just give up on Maven, Artifactory and Oracle.

I am running windows 7-64 with maven installed as a part of Oracle jdev. Company has Artifactory setted up and running on vpn network.... but somethings are not right.

Following simple instructions on:
http://biemond.blogspot.co.uk/2013/07/maven-support-in-weblogic-jdeveloper.html

fails at first instruction:

- Install the oracle maven sync plugin to your local repository
  the command:

  mvn deploy:deploy-file -DpomFile=oracle-maven-sync.12.1.2.pom -Dfile=oracle-maven-sync.12.1.2.jar

the error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy-file (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: The parameters 'url' for goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy-file are missing or invalid -> [Help 1]
```

adding

```
-Durl=file://C:\Users\{user}\.m2
```

seems to install that artifact to my local .m2 repo

```
C:\Users\{user}\.m2\com\oracle\maven\oracle-maven-sync\12.1.2-0-0
```

but only seems, then I get to number 3 on that tutorial:

- mvn com.oracle.maven:oracle-maven-sync:help

gives an error:

```
[ERROR] Error resolving version for plugin 'com.oracle.maven:oracle-maven-sync' from the repositories [local (C:\Users\{user}\.m2), central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)]: Plugin not found in any plugin repository -> [Help 1]
```

So the plugin failed to install?

Oracle Maven repository is password protected due to weird oracle thoughts, *Artifactory has external Central and Oracle repositories* why letting it mirror everything stops maven from even finding deploy module?

here is my settings.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.1.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

  <servers>
    <server>
      <username>user</username>
      <password>xxx</password>
      <id>central</id>
    </server>
    <server>
      <username>user</username>
      <password>xxx</password>
      <id>snapshots</id>
    </server>
  </servers>

  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
          </snapshots>
          <id>central</id>
          <name>libs-release-local</name>
          <url>http://art.host.ru:8081/artifactory/libs-release-local</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
          <snapshots />
          <id>snapshots</id>
          <name>libs-snapshot-local</name>
          <url>http://art.host.ru:8081/artifactory/libs-snapshot-local</url>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
      <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
          </snapshots>
          <id>central</id>
          <name>plugins-release-local</name>
          <url>http://art.host.ru:8081/artifactory/plugins-release-local</url>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
          <snapshots />
          <id>snapshots</id>
          <name>plugins-snapshot-local</name>
          <url>http://art.host.ru:8081/artifactory/plugins-snapshot-local</url>
        </pluginRepository>
      </pluginRepositories>
      <id>artifactory</id>
    </profile>
    <profile>
      <id>oracle-maven</id>
      <properties>
        <oracle-maven-sync.oracleHome>C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home</oracle-maven-sync.oracleHome>
        <oracle-maven-sync.testOnly>false</oracle-maven-sync.testOnly>
        <oracle-maven-sync.failOnError>false</oracle-maven-sync.failOnError>
      </properties>      
    </profile>  

  </profiles>
  <activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>oracle-maven</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use http://jcenter.bintray.com for most of the artifacts

And for Oracle: *oracle-maven-sync* plugin
[oracle instructions](http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/core/MAVEN/config_maven.htm#MAVEN313)

- $ORACLE_HOME = where jdev 12.1.2
- $M2_HOME = $ORACLE_HOME/oracle_common/modules/org.apache.maven_3.0.4
- $M2 = $M2_HOME/bin (add to $PATH)
- artifactory->home->maven settings generate settings.xml put it in ~/.m2
- create local repo in artifactory"oracle-local-12.1.2"
- settings.xml add following code

  ```
  <profiles>
  <profile>
    <properties>
      <oracle-maven-sync.oracleHome>$ORACLE_HOME</oracle-maven-sync.oracleHome>
      <oracle-maven-sync.testOnly>false</oracle-maven-sync.testOnly>
      <oracle-maven-sync.failOnError>false</oracle-maven-sync.failOnError>
      <oracle-maven-sync.serverId>oracle-local-12.1.2</oracle-maven-sync.serverId></properties>
  ```
- artifactory -> username(top right corner) -> enter pass -> unlock -> забрать encrypted password(copy)
- add aquired pass to settings.xml for all
- go to $ORACLE_HOME/oracle_common/plugins/maven/com/oracle/maven/oracle-maven-sync/12.1.2 (use cmd/terminal)
- mvn deploy:deploy-file -DpomFile=oracle-maven-sync-12.1.2.pom -Dfile=oracle-maven-sync-12.1.2.jar
- test it: mvn com.oracle.maven:oracle-maven-sync:help
- push artifacts oracle 12.1.2 mvn com.oracle.maven:oracle-maven-sync:push
- long time wait (~3000 artifacts > 2 hours)
- complete set up of repos and in settings.xml

Comment: Again, you don't need the maven-sync plugin. It complicates things.

Comment: @JBaruch how then i would get artifacts for oracle?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Artifactory knows how to proxy Oracle Maven repository just like any other repository. It will fetch the needed artifacts per your request.

Comment: Oracle repository only has version 12.1.3 artifacts?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think you just follow the wrong guide. All this manual deployment of some random maven plugins is just wrong.
Just follow the simple and detailed instructions in [the Artifactory User Guide](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Advanced+Settings#AdvancedSettings-NetworkSettings) and you're good to go.

Comment: it is Oracle - it is random

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the -Dmaven.repo.local

Do not provide the argument.